# Add cells in data frame in R by every combination of cells in other rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a data frame in R of c columns and r rows. I have multiple data frames. The number of columns will remain constant (12 in real life, but 3 in this example). The number of rows changes, but is usually between 4 and 7. I need to separately sum each cell in row 1 iteratively to all the cells in row 2, to then populate a vector of those sums.

I've figured out how to populate the vector when I have exactly two rows, but how do I write a script for a larger and unspecified number of rows?

Here's some example data:

```
set.seed(3)

# vector of length ncol^nrow
vc <- 3^2 

# sample data frame of 3 columns and 2 rows
df <- data.frame(
  c1 = sample.int(10,2),
  c2 = sample.int(10,2),
  c3 = sample.int(10,2)
)
df

for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
  for(k in 1:ncol(df)){
    
    # test to make sure I'm indexing to populate vc correctly
    #  print( k + (j-1) * ncol(df) )
    
    # populate vc with the sum of the cells
    vc[ k + (j-1) * ncol(df)   ] <- df[1,j] + df[2,k]
  
  }
}

vc

# visual process for vc:
# vc <- 5+7, 5+8, 5+4, 4+7, 4+8, 4+4, 8+7, 8+8, 8+4

# correct final result for vc:
# vc <- c(12, 13, 9, 11, 12, 8, 15, 16, 12)
```

Comment: With 7 rows of 12 choices, that'd be a vector 13.8 billion long (12^7), is that understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: Conceptually, yes. (I won't actually have to do the brute force calculation for the data frames with seven rows. I'll just run this on data frames of 3 to 5 rows. I also may omit the 11th and 12th columns for certain data frames. If I have a df with lots of rows and I need all 12 columns, I'll figure out some sort of random sampling of the subset later.)

Comment: apologies.. but isn't it `c x c x (r choose 2)` summatiion operations that need to be done? Perhaps I don't understand. But in the example above, we have 2x3 df, which is 3 columns x 3 columns x (2 choose 2), which is 9..

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood, but I was thinking you could use `outer()` in this function below?

```
f <- function(df) {
  m <- as.matrix(df)
  sapply(combn(1:nrow(m),2,simplify = F),\(i) outer(m[i[2],],m[i[1],],"+"))
}
```

Usage:

```
f(df)
```

Output

```
      [,1]
 [1,]   12
 [2,]   13
 [3,]    9
 [4,]   11
 [5,]   12
 [6,]    8
 [7,]   15
 [8,]   16
 [9,]   12
```

If you have a 4 rows x 5 columns dataframe, then there are `5*5*(4 choose 2) = 150` summations, like this:

```
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame(
  c1 = sample.int(10,4),
  c2 = sample.int(10,4),
  c3 = sample.int(10,4),
  c4 = sample.int(10,4),
  c5 = sample.int(10,4))

f(df)
```

Output:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]   11    6    8   13   15   10
 [2,]    8   10    9   17   16   11
 [3,]    9    5    8   12   15   10
 [4,]    9    8    4   15   11    6
 [5,]    3    5    8   12   15   10
 [6,]   12    7    9   10   12   14
 [7,]    9   11   10   14   13   15
 [8,]   10    6    9    9   12   14
 [9,]   10    9    5   12    8   10
[10,]    4    6    9    9   12   14
[11,]   19   14   16   11   13    9
[12,]   16   18   17   15   14   10
[13,]   17   13   16   10   13    9
[14,]   17   16   12   13    9    5
[15,]   11   13   16   10   13    9
[16,]   14    9   11   11   13   12
[17,]   11   13   12   15   14   13
[18,]   12    8   11   10   13   12
[19,]   12   11    7   13    9    8
[20,]    6    8   11   10   13   12
[21,]   13    8   10    5    7    9
[22,]   10   12   11    9    8   10
[23,]   11    7   10    4    7    9
[24,]   11   10    6    7    3    5
[25,]    5    7   10    4    7    9
```